# What column type in Oracle can take full range of java double values

Tags: java, oracle, double

What column type in Oracle 10g can be used to store any value of java double up to and including Double.MAX_VALUE and Double.MIN_VALUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oracle SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref80):

> The NUMBER datatype stores zero as well as positive and negative fixed numbers with absolute values from 1.0 x 10^-130 to (but not including) 1.0 x 10^126.

It looks like you may need [BINARY_DOUBLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i140176):

> Maximum positive finite value: 1.79769313486231E+308
>
> Minimum positive finite value: 2.22507485850720E-308

Comment: The docs say: "A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double, (2-2**52)·2**1023". I use ** to mean exponentiation. Entering this expression into Windows calculator gives 1,797693134862315708145274237317e+308.

Comment: Oracle's BINARY_DOUBLE does not store the IEEE754 value -0, Java does.

Comment: What the heck is -0 as opposed to 0? ;-)

Comment: I thought that would be it. For some reason I got oracle jdbc driwer

Comment: .. to throw an exception when inserting close to max/min values.